# react native can't get component to show

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native. I am developing a simple app but I can't get the Tabs component to show.

index.ios.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Index from './app/Index';

export default class App1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Index />
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App1', () => App1);
```

app/Index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Tabs from './Router';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
});

export default class Index extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View><Tabs /></View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

app/Router.js (Tabs component):

```
import React from 'react';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import Calendar from './screens/Calendar';
import RecycleLocation from './screens/RecycleLocation';

const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  Calendar: {
    screen: Calendar,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBar: {
        icon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon type="font-awesome" name="calendar" size={24} color={tintColor} />,
      },
    },
  },
  RecycleLocation: {
    screen: RecycleLocation,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBar: {
        label: 'Recycle Location',
        icon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon type="font-awesome" name="map" size={24} color={tintColor} />,
      },
    },
  },
});

export default Tabs;
```

In app/Index.js, if I do this, it works fine:

```
export default class Index extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Tabs />
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: have you export StatusBarBackground and Tabs ?

Comment: _"But if I just return it works fine"_ - How'd you mean?

Comment: some troubleshooting tip . Add  `backgroundColor: 'red'` to your container style

Comment: Yep, export all components. I also changed the backgroundColor to red. All it did was showing a red screen without any content. I edited the original post to include more info.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working by removing View element around Tabs component.

```
export default class Index extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // <Tabs />
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View><StatusBarBackground /></View>
        <Tabs />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Still confused why Tabs won't work with View elements around it.